# Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Issue: this error appear when i try to load a Tensorflow SavedModel.

```
model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/test')
```

```
from tensorflow import keras
model_1 = keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/test')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-57-429e9165fb9a> in <module>
      1 from tensorflow import keras
----> 2 model_1 = keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/test')

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/function_deserialization.py in restored_function_body(*args, **kwargs)
    293               index + 1, _pretty_format_positional(positional), keyword))
    294     raise ValueError(
--> 295         "Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the "
    296         f"SavedModel. Got:\n  {_pretty_format_positional(args)}\n  Keyword "
    297         f"arguments: {kwargs}\n\n Expected these arguments to match one of the "

ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * tf.RaggedTensor(values=tf.RaggedTensor(values=Tensor("inputs:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int32), row_splits=Tensor("inputs_2:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)), row_splits=Tensor("inputs_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64))
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

 Expected these arguments to match one of the following 2 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * [RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None, None]), tf.int32, 2, tf.int64)]
    * True
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * [RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None, None]), tf.int32, 2, tf.int64)]
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

I was trying to load a SavedModel from tensorflow in Colab and this error pop up. The model is saved correctly in the directory, but then I'm unable to reload it. I can't understand if this is an issue with the model itself of with load_model function.[This is the SavedModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFJiQ.png)

I tried to upgrade/update, reinstall tf, etc. but nothing changed. I also tried to save the model in hdf5 format, but apparently with model.save I can't save it in that format (I followed the tf tutorial).